# What parts of Italy should you go to for anchovy pizza?

Tags: pizza

Is there a specific region of Italy that is known for anchovy pizza? Can you get that in all of Italy or is that specific to a region?

Can you actually get a buffalo mozzarella anchovy pizza?

Im trying to flesh out the specifics of my culinary bucket list.

I’m assuming Italians actually do anchovies on pizza. I know they have nothing but disdain for those who put pineapple on pizza.

Comment: I've seen pineapple on pizza in Italy, not often but it's done, and not just in tourist places.

Comment: Well all I can say according to Claudio Reineri it is not real pizza. That is just a side note. I can remove if it detracts from the main premise of the question.

Comment: Ask a group of Italians what is 'Italian' and what isn't and you'll likely get a different answer from each.

Comment: Hey, you seem confused about what you want to ask.  I've answered your first question.  If you have additional questions about cheese on pizza, I suggest asking them in separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Napoli.

Prior to [the blessing of Pizza Margharita](https://www.visitnaples.eu/en/neapolitanity/flavours-of-naples/neapolitan-history-through-the-history-of-pizza-margherita) as the official pizza of Napoli, the locals equally enjoyed pizza with tomato sauce and anchovies.  So much so, that this pizza is still known as [Pizza Napoli](https://www.italianfoodforever.com/2015/01/pizza-napoli-pizza-with-anchovies/).

So if you're looking for a traditional, "canonical" anchovy pizza, that's the place to go.

Comment: Thank you, I did think anyone with a good knowledge about Italy would be able to tell what kind of Italians are anchovy on pizza Italians

Answer (score 1):

I expect anchovy pizza (or variation of) be available pretty much everywhere a pizza is made in Italy, maybe more in the south part of Italy (Rome, Naples...)

Look for "Pizza Romana".

Your best bet is to go to Naples.

For example (rome) : https://katieparla.com/daily-food-photo-pizzariums-anchovy-pizza/

I can't say I've seen Ricotta on pizza while traveling in Italy.

Comment: Ah yes I was thinking of buffalo mozerella

Comment: "Proper" Buffalo Mozzarella comes from Campania and surrounding areas (but is found everywhere in Italy)

Comment: I know it is subjective but is the buffalo cheese the ultimate pizza cheese?

Comment: Neil: that's exactly the kind of question that gets closed as "opinion-based", so I don't suggest posting it.  Again, ask three Italians and you'll get five opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Anchovies are very much a staple ingredient in many Italian dishes, but as Max said in his answer, the salty, briny flavor is more of a "thing" in Middle/Southern Italy. I do however think it's very much possible to get anchovy pizza in any proper restaurant that offers pizza. It's more restaurant specific than region specific.

The same goes for buffalo mozzarella. As it is a somewhat premium ingredient, most restaurants will offer it at a premium or not all. You will then typically find a normal "Pizza Margherita" and a "Pizza di Buffala" or "Pizza Margherita (con Mozzarella di Buffalla)" right next to it. Expect to pay around 1-2€ more.

So if you want a pizza with both buffalo mozzarella and anchovies (nothing else might be a bit weird to be honest) you can most likely simply ask for it.